# Independence/conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

Does $P(A|B,C) = P(A|C) =>  P(A,B) = P(A)*P(B)?$
And if so, how do I prove it?

I would intuitively say this is true since $P(A|B) = P(A)$ would mean $A$ and $B$ are independent and hence $P(A,B) =  P(A)*P(B)$.

Comment: Suppose $B=C=A$.

Comment: LHS means A and B are independent conditional on C.

Comment: It only implies conditional independence: A and B are independent given C.